# declare integer pointer on stack and assign value versus on heap

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory

using heap I have the following:

```
int *cnt = malloc(sizeof(int));
cnt[0] = 5;
*cnt = 0;
```

I'm declaring a pointer and malloc space for 1 int
I can assign either by cnt[0] = 5 or *cnt = 0.  In this example the second assignment overwrites the first

How do I do this using the stack?

```
int *cnt = NULL;
```

does that assign any memory from the stack?  How do I assign a value to cnt? (i.e an integer, not address)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a pointer if you're using the stack.  You can just do:

```
int cnt[1];
cnt[0] = 5;
*cnt = 0;
```

The first assignment is overwritten by the second and will probably be optimized away.

If you really want a pointer variable, you can instead do:

```
int cnt_var;
int *cnt = &cnt_var;
cnt[0] = 5;
*cnt = 0;
```

This takes a little more stack space, since it's allocating both the `int` variable and an `int *` pointer.